# Shmap 3.2 recover pointer of shared memory

Tags: c, data-structures, dictionary, shared-memory

http://shmap.sourceforge.net/

My question is: How can i safe away a "reference/pointer" in order to access the datastructure later?

As described the datastructure is saved in shared memory. It is also visible after initialization that there is a new semaphore array listed in linux ipcs.

The Initialization part is straight forward and described in the API page, my assumption would be that in the shmap_opts (initializer parameter struct) the p_mem must be the pointer to the original structure.

Has somebody more expirience with this library, if your expertise of c is good you might spot it quicker than i do. My aim is to fill the datastructure and keep the pointer address in a file and later use a second process to actually retreive the datastructure and fill it again with data.

Thanks for your help.

Here is also a direct code view, most people probably haven't used this library.

http://www.koders.com/c/fid6F96AC6995CC50643473EB1155AD37F0353612F0.aspx?s=btree#L48

Answer (score 0):

I have talked to the holder of this sourceforge project. He confirmed that currently this is only working for forked processes and this issue cannot be resolved without extending the current library.